# Joining numbers together with a string

Tags: javascript, string

I know that for an array `join()` can be used to produce what I am trying to accomplish here, but I am working with a string. What method would work with a string?

I want my output to look like "3 then 4 then 5 then 6 then 7", etc.

I've come close to getting what I am looking for but my current code adds an extra "then" at the end, which is not what I want:

```
let appendString = '';
let then = ' then ';

function countUp(start) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){     
    appendString += (start++) + then; 
  }   
  console.log(appendString); 
}
```

I do not want solutions, I just would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: please add an example of call and wanted result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what about this?

```js
let appendString = '';
let then = ' then ';
function countUp(start) {
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){     
  appendString += (start++)
  if(i<9){
    appendString+=then
  }
  
}   
console.log(appendString); 
}
```

or

```js
let appendArray = [];
let then = ' then ';
function countUp(start) {
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){     
  appendArray.push(start++);
}   

console.log(appendArray.join(then)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to not spoil the fun for you.

Think of it like this. If you have an array that has all your numbers, can you join them using .join ?

Now the question will be how to initialise an array with the numbers you want.
Try looking into array initialisations.

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't just change it to an array. I feel a little dumb lol but I did get the solution I was looking for. I was just limiting myself.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that with an array you can use `join`. The thing is that you can turn a series of sequential numbers to an array easily:

```js
function countUp(start, end, then) {
    let arr = Array.from({length: end-start+1}, (_, i) => start + i);
    return arr.join(then);
}

console.log(countUp(1, 10, ' then '));
```